# How to change styling of a <button> tag using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am really confused about why this code doesn't work for styling a button. Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working??

```css
.button2 {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallButtons" style="clear: both;">
 <button class="button2">ADD TO REGISTRY</button>
 <button class="button2">ADD TO LIST</button>
 <button class="button2">SHARE</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/865eg40w/#&togetherjs=6RiA5b06zJ

Comment: what isn't working, looks green to me?

Comment: Your Snippet works for me

Comment: It's working fine. Check snippet in your question.

Comment: Browser issue maybe??

Comment: The Snippet works but the code in your jsFiddle is wrong. Which one are you having the problem with?

Comment: The Fiddle. Looks like people editing the crap out of it

Comment: Fiddle is the same as my snippet

Comment: nope. In html you had ID and in css you were targeting class

Comment: *Fiddle is the same as my snippet* Maybe it was, but it definitely isn't any more! So are you saying that the snippet isn't working for you either, or that the snippet is working but the same code isn't working for you on your site? If the snippet *is* working for you, then we need to see the actual site where it is not working.

Comment: This is what is on my site, and it's not working:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AF39bsh1GU

Comment: But is the *snippet* working for you? If it is, then we need to see *your site* because there could be something else affecting it. The link to the fiddle is useless at this stage - it is constantly being changed by others so its impossible to try to debug anything on it :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Ok, I edited the snippet above to show what I have on my website

Comment: I've figured out what's happening - its your white space and I've created a snippet in an answer to demonstrate. I've no idea why there's a problem with your white space, but at least you know how to fix it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the white space in your css. 
I have copied your css & html below and also made a duplicate copy that is identical in every way except for 2 things:

- my css class is called `.button22` (so we can test both classes in
  the same snippet)
- I deleted all thw white space between the lines of your CSS and then
  added them back using the space bar.

Your CSS doesn't work, but my identical CSS except for the white space does - run the snippet and you'll see both rows of buttons.

```css
.button2 {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.button22 {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;

}
```

```html
<div class="smallButtons" style="clear: both;">
 <button class="button2">ADD TO REGISTRY</button>
 <button class="button2">ADD TO LIST</button>
 <button class="button2">SHARE</button>
</div>


<div class="smallButtons" style="clear: both;">
 <button class="button22">ADD TO REGISTRY</button>
 <button class="button22">ADD TO LIST</button>
 <button class="button22">SHARE</button>
</div>
```

As to *why* the whitespace in yours is breaking it, I can't answer,  but I can tell you that replacing it will solve the problem!

Comment: New one to me too! Check whereever you copied the code from when you made the snippet, maybe there is some strange encoding set or something. Anyway, at least you know how to stop it happening, if not why! :-)

Answer (score 2):

On your fiddle there are some extra spaces before `.button2` class. Just remove that and you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try open with other web browser

Comment: Yeah, that was my other thought. Maybe a browser issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button2 { 
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button2">
This is a Button
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the padding doesn't show up or the white text but it shows up in the edited snippet at the top. I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Try id instead of class in your html.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button2 { 
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button2">
This is a Button
</button>
```

Put your button2 class in CSS file and add it in your HTML page.

Comment: So why does your snippet work and mine up top doesn't?

Comment: I think you will not link your CSS file properly on HTML page.

Comment: Here is my link `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">` to CSS stylesheet located in the same directory as my HTML

Comment: Are HTML and CSS both files in the same directory??